# Bootstrap 3 modal with external items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 modal and within the modal there is a Facebook like button and Facebook comments plug in, but they don't show.

Is this due to the same-origin policy and is there another solution to allow this?

Comment: they don't show as in ? can you detect them via firebug ?

Comment: No, the simply don't pull the content in from FB - work perfectly on non-modal pages with exactly the same code

Comment: try passing the value before the modal button click and try calling the modal

Comment: the code is within the modal content, which is loaded dynamically so that won't work unfortunately